Company Repo with multiple projects and parent POM
We use an company repo and have about 20 Java Maven projects. Unfortunately, the IP address of the repo has now changed. Now I have to change the repo address in all 20 projects. I am now looking for an easier way to do this. That you only need to change the address once, for future changes. I have read that this can be done with a parent pom. Since we already had a BOM anyway, I have entered the following there:
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>companyRepo</id>
        <url>https://repo.intern.de/repo/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>

But unfortunately that didn't help, it can't find the BOM at all. It is already in the company repo. An entry in the settings.xml does not help either.
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>companyRepo</id>
        <url>https://repo.intern.de/repo/</url>
        <mirrorOf>external:http:*</mirrorOf>
        <blocked>false</blocked>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>

How can I solve this? Google has unfortunately not helped me.
